# Why do I get this result with a chi- square test?

Tags: interpretation, hypothesis-testing, chi-square-test

I have a question about the chi squared independence test, I'm working on dataset and I'm interested in finding the link between the categories of product and the gender, I plot my contingency table.

contingency_table :-

[image]

I found that  p-value is1.54*10-5 implying that my variables are correlated. I don't really understand how is it possible because the proportion between man and women for each category are very similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proportion between men and women within three product categories has no connection with chi-squared test of independence. Sex (male versus female) does generally have strong impact on buying a particular product category. A very low p value is indicative of fact that there is strong evidence for an association between two variables. Chi-square statistic gives the magnitude of association or relationship between two variables.